# Make XML elements required based on attribute values in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, msxml

My requirement is to have an XSD file which checks the elements based on attribute values. I was able to write XSD up to a point where I can restrict the attribute values of `Application/@Type`. Can anyone help me to complete the XSD file where I can make some elements required based on the `Application/@Type` attribute?

I want to make

- `PackageArg` required only when `Application/@Type` is "Batch"
- `Version` required only when `Application/@Type` is "Service"
- `Project` required only when `Application/@Type` is Web" or "Service"

**XML File**

```
<Applications>        
    <Application Name="ConfigManagement" Type="Web">            
        <ProjectDirName>ConfigManagement</ProjectDirName>
        <Project>Web.ConfigManagement.csproj</Project>
        <OutputDirName>ConfigManagement</OutputDirName>            
    </Application>
    <Application Name="Util" Type="Web">            
        <ProjectDirName>Web</ProjectDirName>
        <Project>Web.csproj</Project>        
        <OutputDirName>Util</OutputDirName>    
    </Application>
    <Application Name="ConfigService" Type="Service">
        <ProjectDirName>WebServices\ConfigService</ProjectDirName>
        <Project>ConfigService.csproj</Project>    
        <Version>2015\04</Version>
        <OutputDirName>ConfigService</OutputDirName>
    </Application>
    <Application Name="DeliverEmail" Type="Batch">        
        <ProjectDirName>\Batch\DeliverEmail</ProjectDirName>
        <PackageArg>Release</PackageArg>        
        <OutputDirName>Tidal\DeliverEmail</OutputDirName>            
    </Application>
</Applications>
```

**XSD File**

```
<xs:element name="Applications" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Application" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:all>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ProjectDirName"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Project" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Version" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="PackageArg" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="OutputDirName"/>
          </xs:all>
          <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="optional"/>
          <xs:attribute name="Type" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Web"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Batch"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Service"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Please add your linked material directly into your question.  It'd also be helpful if you provided an example of what you want to be considered valid and what you want to be excluded as invalid.  Also, please do not use tags that are not specific to your question - this is not a C# question specifically.

Comment: @DanField is right -- your question should be self-contained.  I've fixed that for you this time, but please include all needed material in your question in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for editing and suggestions. I will follow them next time I post question.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**  OP has edited question to remove the use of `xs:assert` and has stated in comments that validation must take place in C#.  The answer to OP's question now becomes:

***You cannot enforce a constraint that varies the requiredness of an element based on an attribute value using XSD 1.0, and Microsoft does not support XSD 1.1, therefore you must either relax your constraints or check them outside of your XSD.***

---

## Original XSD 1.1 answer

(Retained for benefit of future readers)

You're close, but your assertion,

```
      <xs:assert test="count(./PackageArg[@type eq 'Batch']) eq 1"/>
```

tests for `@type` on `PackageArg` when it should test for `@Type` on `Application`.

The following XSD will validate your XML and enforce your attribute-dependent requirements:

### XSD 1.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="Applications">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Application" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ProjectDirName"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Project" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Version" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="PackageArg" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="OutputDirName"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Type" use="required">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="Web"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="Batch"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="Service"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:assert test="PackageArg or @Type != 'Batch'"/>
            <xs:assert test="Version or @Type != 'Service'"/>
            <xs:assert test="Project or not(@Type = 'Web' or @Type = 'Service')"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Be aware that Microsoft does not support XSD 1.1.  (You've tagged your question with 'msxml').

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I was trying different things and I included the wrong line.

Comment: Wrong line?  Do you mean wrong 'tag' (msxml)?   More importantly, does this answer help you?

Comment: i didnt mean to include the Assert tag. i want to use the xsd file in C#, so i cant use XSD1.1.

Comment: Well, having `xs:assert` in your XSD implies that you're ok using XSD 1.1.  **You cannot enforce your requirements in XSD 1.0; you need XSD 1.1**, or you'll have to enforce your attribute-based element requiredness constraint outside of XSD.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i edited my question. Thank you for suggestion